# How do i return a promise and object from firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Just a heads up, this my first day using cloud functions. I have a cloud function that returns an object to my client after verifying some details. I also want to use this function to write to my firestore database. But to write to my database i have to return a promise from my function. How do i do both and make this work? Here's my code.

```
export const verifyDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const chosenUsername = data.username;
    const chosenEmail = data.email;

    const allEmails: string[] = [];
    const allUsernames: string[] = [];

    let usernameExists = false;
    let emailExists = false;

    await admin.firestore().collection('Users').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                allEmails.push(doc.data().email);
                allUsernames.push(doc.data().username);
            })

            allEmails.forEach((email) => {
                if (email === chosenEmail) {
                    emailExists = true;
                }
            });

            allUsernames.forEach((username) => {
                if (username === chosenUsername) {
                    usernameExists = true;
                }
            });

            if (!usernameExists && !emailExists) {
                registerDetails(chosenUsername, chosenEmail);
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error retrieving firestore documents', error);
        });

    return { usernameExists: usernameExists, emailExists: emailExists };

});


export const registerDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').add({
        email: data.chosenEmail,
        username: data.chosenUsername
    });
});
```

I tried using another https callback function and call it within the main function. This doesn't  write to my database but it does return my object. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out the contents of the `registerDetails` function so both onCall functions can use it...

```
async function addUser(data) {
  return admin.firestore().collection('Users').add({
    email: data.chosenEmail,
    username: data.chosenUsername
  })
}
```

Now `verifyDetails` can use it like this...

```
export const verifyDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('Users').get()
  // code from the OP here.
  // because we used await, the code doesn't have to be in a then block
  
  await addUser({ chosenEmail, chosenUsername })
  return { usernameExists: usernameExists, emailExists: emailExists };
})
```

and `registerDetails` can use it like this...

```
export const registerDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return addUser(data)
})
```

Note that verifyDetails doesn't return a promise, but it awaits the async work, which also works.